# Python Selenium: Unable to fetch table content

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to access [this](https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/2114-Bigelow-Ave-N-Seattle-WA-98109/48749425_zpid/) URL, here I have to fetch table under *Price / Tax History* section. Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
import os, sys
from multiprocessing import Pool
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/2114-Bigelow-Ave-N-Seattle-WA-98109/48749425_zpid/')
sleep(10)
p_history = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#tax-price-history  table tr > td')
    for p in p_history:
        print(p.text)
```

it is not printing text.

**Update** Screen of the section required:

[image]

**Update#2**

Ran against PhantomJS and here you can see *loader* image in the section(Scroll the image)

[image]

Comment: Can you try with the following query selector, note that it's not extensible and would work on only first row, for that you would need to do few more changes:        document.querySelector('#tax-price-history tbody tr td:nth-child(3)')

Comment: @AnupamSaini First off, I am using Python, second I did try this and did not work

Comment: which text you are trying to fetch exactly, there are few td which doesn't have any text, they have span and some more span inside them and then text.

Comment: @GaurangShah Question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell selenium to use `WebDriverWait` and `expected_conditions` to find the element once it's loaded.

You need a reference to an element that doesn't exist on page load, but should be there once the Ajax request is complete. It looks like `#tax-price-history table` should fulfil that requirement.

try:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
parent = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
    By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#tax-price-history table')))

p_history = parent.find_element_by_css_selector('td')
```

If the element isn't found in the time limit specified in `wait` you'll get an error

Comment: `    value = method(self._driver)TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: ah. the syntax is quite different in python. I'll edit the answer